# Getting a value stored procedure C#

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I have tried a variety of ways, but no luck. Using Microsoft Visual Studio and SQL Server 2005
here is the c# code  and sql code

```
List<SqlParameter>  _params3 = new List<SqlParameter>();
_params3.Add(new SqlParameter("@startdate", txtDateFrom.Text));
_params3.Add(new SqlParameter("@enddate", txtDateTo.Text));
_params3.Add(new SqlParameter("@days", extendedDays));

extendedDays = Convert.ToInt32(DAL.executeStoredProcedureScalar(
                   "Time_Difference_Calc", _params3));
```

SQL code:

```
set ANSI_NULLS ON
set QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
go


ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Time_Difference_Calc]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @startdate datetime,
    @enddate datetime,
    @days int output
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    set @days = (Select RawDays
    - NumWeeks * 2
    + CASE WHEN StartWD = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    - CASE WHEN EndWD = 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    + 1
    AS Result
    FROM
    (SELECT Datepart(dw,@startdate) as StartWD,
    Datepart(dw,@enddate) as EndWD,
    DateDiff(d,@startdate,@enddate) as RawDays,
    DateDiff(wk,@startdate,@enddate) as NumWeeks
    ) A)

    --SET @ReturnValue = @days
    RETURN @days
END
```

I can run it on the database just fine..put 2 dates in.. works fine for what I need..

But whenever I actually run it in the page.. always get

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object."
>   source error : return cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

Any help is appreciated. Pretty much the idea is I just want to get extended days equal to whatever the stored procedure returns.

Comment: Can you put more of your C# code in here.. I can see a few things off the bat that are wrong as well.. also what ver of VS are you using...? List<SqlParameter>  _params3 = new List<SqlParameter>(); why are you doing this when you should be using the SQLCommand Object and the SQLConnection Object ..??

Comment: What's DAL.executeStoredProcedureScalar?  Can you post the code of that?

Comment: Instead of posting the code for DAL.executeStoredProcedureScalar. I'd say at a minimum delete that method, and potentially the whole DAL class definition and switch to doing things the right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your stored procedure to select the value instead of using a parameter. Then you can continue to use `ExecuteScalar`.

The stored proc would be something like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Time_Difference_Calc]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @startdate datetime,
    @enddate datetime
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    Select RawDays
    - NumWeeks * 2
    + CASE WHEN StartWD = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    - CASE WHEN EndWD = 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    + 1
    AS Result
    FROM
    (SELECT Datepart(dw,@startdate) as StartWD,
    Datepart(dw,@enddate) as EndWD,
    DateDiff(d,@startdate,@enddate) as RawDays,
    DateDiff(wk,@startdate,@enddate) as NumWeeks
    ) A
END
```

Another thing to consider, if you're only calling this from an app, then the stored proc is kind of useless. You don't need SQL Server to do this calculation, and it's simpler to do in code.

Answer (score 4):

You need to set the @day's parameter's [`Direction`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.direction.aspx) property to [`ParameterDirection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.parameterdirection.aspx)`.Output`

Also, you will have to get the value out of the @day [`SqlParamater`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx).[`Value`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.value.aspx) property

Answer (score 3):

Not being able to see the actual code that invokes the SQL, it's hard to be certain, but I'm pretty sure you ought to be calling ExecuteNonQuery for this - you're not actually selecting any return values, hence the null reference exception when your code is trying to retrieve a scalar value.

If your stored procedure had a section in it along the lines of `SELECT TOP 1 foo FROM bar WHERE baz = @quux;` then ExecuteScalar (or your equivalent of it) would be approriate.  However, you're returning the value as an output parameter, so it's a non-query.

Note: the other answers are correct about needing to set the parameter direction, but this is why you're getting the NullReferenceException.

Comment: +1: A Scalar call means "get the first field of the first record", which is NOT what the stored proc is doing.  It's returning an output parameter.  In that case you should do an ExecuteNonQuery and simply read the parameter.

Answer (score 1):

```
_params3.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
```

exec the proc

```
extendedDays = Convert.ToInt32(_params3.Value);
```

Comment: ok, just add the code to: new SqlParameter("@days", extendedDays)
or create a parameter called p3 with the correct direction and then add it to the list. It was small typo, no need to downvote

Answer (score 0):

```
SqlParameter daysParameter = new SqlParameter("@days", extendedDays);
    daysParameter .Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    _params3.Parameters.Add(daysParameter );
```

should do the trick